# Kibana 4,maps not showing specific areas

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, kibana-4

In Kibana 3, I was able to use three types of maps US,Europe and the World Map. But in the Kibana 4,I can only see a wolrd map version. For my data purposes I need to have only the US one. Can anybody help me on this?.

Comment: You can zoom and show a particular area alone. This is saved between sessions. I hope that should work for you.

Comment: @VineethMohan I think that is the right solution for the question. Can you post it as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can zoom and show a particular area alone. This is saved between sessions. Hence it should work fine for you.